# Expiration time of password reset tokens

Tags: security, brute-force, forgot-password

When users forget their passwords, they can reset it (on most websites). They do so by receiving an email with a reset-token, then using that to set a new password. This token usually expires after a while to protect against guessing.

Let's say the token is 256-bit. Bruteforcing it with lots of supercomputers still takes (very roughly) 10^50 years. I.e. it cannot be done with current knowledge, definitely not within 1 hour (regular expiration time). Now the question is: why do we protect against guessing at all?

Comment: Assuming you meant 256 byte. Also You never mentioned encryption method. Even with a huge key if you have poor encryption it is trivial to crack.

Comment: No I meant bit, just a number, no encryption key. It's basically just about guessing a 256-bit number.

Comment: Ah sure, ye a long time.

Answer (score 4):

Guessing is not really what you're protecting it from. As you've figured, the entropy size alone takes care of that.

The expiration serves primarily to mitigate possible unauthorized access of that token, as there are many ways it can be leaked from an email message. Exactly like why you shouldn't send a user's password to their email address.
Somebody else might have temporary access to the email account, happens to be reading together with the account owner, or standing behind them, etc. All kinds of shenanigans are possible.

Plus, nobody wants a database table full of old, but supposedly temporary one-time tokens - every developer likes to cleanup garbage data.

Comment: You can't really prevent from someone else having access to the email account, because that person can just request a new token at that time I'd say. Protecting against someone looking over your shoulder is avoided by two things. First, the token is 256-bit randomness, not easy to rembember. Second, you can hide it in the button (html-email). (Cleaning up your database is a fine argument I guess, but not so much security related and something that can surely wait 48 hours for example.)

Comment: Sure, you can do a lot of small cosmetic things to hide the token, but none gurantee it and that's not really the point - the process has to be secure by design, not reliant on some front-end sorcery. And yes, of course if somebody has permanent access to the account can request a new key, but the key words here are "leak" and "temporary".